# shortest encoding for Guid for use in a URL

Tags: compression, guid, friendly-url

[Mads Kristensen](http://madskristensen.net/post/a-shorter-and-url-friendly-guid) got one down to 00amyWGct0y_ze4lIsj2Mw

Can it go smaller than that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like there are only [73](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm) characters that can be used unescaped in a URL.  IF that's the case, you could convert the 128-bit number to base 73, and have a 21 character URL.

IF you can find 85 legal characters, you can get down to a 20 character URL.

Comment: So we're saving 9 characters on the URL?  I find it actually easier to read/recite the hexadecimal than something like 00amyWGct0y_ze4lIsj2Mw

Comment: @hometoast: Yeah, well, that didn't seem to be a constraint for the OP. ;)

Comment: I used an Ascii85 encoding for writing a Guid to a database column in 20 ASCII characters. I've posted the C# code in case it is useful. The specific character set may be different for a URL encoding, but you can pick whichever characters suit your application. It's available here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827627/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-encode-an-arbitrary-guid-into-readable-ascii-3/4211088#4211088

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting the 73 number from -- in http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.3 there are only 66 unreserved chars: 'A-Z', 'a-z', '0-9', '-', '.', '_', and '~'.  What are the other 7 characters?

Comment: @slacy: From the page linked; it lists `A-Za-z0-9` and `$-_.+!*'(),`, drawn from RFC 1738 section 2.2.  Looks like RFC 3986 that you referenced updates RFC 1738.  The 7 characters `$+!*(),` appear in RFC 3986 section 2.2 as reserved characters as sub-delimiters.  So those 7 characters came from 1994-2005, and it's now 66 characters as of 2005.

Answer (score 5):

A GUID looks like this c9a646d3-9c61-4cb7-bfcd-ee2522c8f633 - that's 32 hex digits, each encoding 4 bits, so 128 bits in total

A base64 encoding uses 6 bits per symbol, which is easy to achieve with URL safe chars to give a 22 char encoded string. As others have noted, you could with with 73 url safe symbols and encoded as a base 73 number to give 21 chars.

Comment: How did you derive the "6 bits out of an URL-safe character" bit?

Comment: There aren't 127 URL safe characters, so assumed 6 bits would be the maximum.

Comment: 6 bits is base64, which the original link went to.  If you can get more than 64 characters, say, 85, you could convert the 128-bit number to base 85 and get down to 20 characters.  It just won't be as nice as base64.

Comment: Base64 uses 6 bits.  You would have to replace the "/" from the list of Base64 characters, though.

Comment: @Dominic: Base64 = 6 bits per byte of actual data.