# How to convert from base-256 to base-N, where N is higher than 16?

Tags: .net, algorithm

I need to convert an array of bytes to another base, namely 85. In math terms the question is how to convert from base-256 to base-85 in the most efficient way?

This question is inspired by my previous question - [What is the most efficient way to encode an arbitrary GUID into readable ASCII (33-127)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827627/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-encode-an-arbitrary-guid-into-readable-ascii-3)

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need something more efficient than converting from base 256 to base 10 and then to base 85 or are you looking for pointers on implementing this?

Comment: Pointers are good enough. I would like to avoid intermediate results, like base-10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this? http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/10/c-implementation-of-ascii85.html

Comment: Looks like we did the same thing, only our input is always a byte array representing some guid, so we were able to optimize the solution by encoding two UInt64 values representing the guid into two 10 byte base-85 strings. But otherwise, this is the same code. Good to know.