Is there way to convert a 38 digit number into a String of length 18 to 20 without any special character?
I have an use case where I need to encode a 38 digit number into a string of length 18 to 20.
I'm using a ByteBuffer with capacity of 16 bytes in java to store two long values. Then I try to encode it to a string without any special characters. I tried base32 encoding which resulted in string of length 26, but I need a much smaller string for my use case.
Is there any workaround for this?
By special characters, I mean excluding anything that is not in the A-Z or 0-9 range.

Can you specify what you understand by "special characters"? No extended ascii, no punctuation marks?

afaik, the smallest number of symbols in base N needed would be given by nBits/Math.log(nBits); that is to say 128/Math.log(128);  == 26.380709319112476

Related question (about GUID, but a GUID also has 128 bits): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827627/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-encode-an-arbitrary-guid-into-readable-ascii

Maybe instead or in addition to encoding you might want to look for a number compression algorithm. I don't have any particular in mind but there's probably some suitable algorithm out there.

Math - 38 digit number: 10³⁸ values; A-Z and 0-9 36 symbols;  so we need log₃₆ (10³⁸) = 24.42 characters ( 25 characters: 36²⁵ ~ 8*10³⁸ )

TL;DR: No, there is no way.

what about also using lowercase characters?

@user85421  I don't have an option to use lowercase

Hola Dharun, Starting from 36 characters, the largest number that can be stored in a string of length 20, is: 481_229803_398374_426442_198455_156736 (33 characters), to achieve what you want, you need 65 characters, and you can display up to: 117_809547_936177_440979_200839_996337_890625 (39 characters), that is, if you can't use more characters and you are limited to a string of length 20... it's impossible.

No, I'm fairly certain it can't be done. Remember that characters are binary data.  They are just interpreted as characters when printed for human consumption. Due to their nature, binary numbers are usually "packed" as efficiently as possible.  Encoding in something like a Base64character set (which coincidentally is identical to your requirements of a-zA-Z0-9 plus \+ and = for padding), increases the size of the string relative to the original information.  Due to packing every 6 bits of source converted to an 8 bit character you increase the values original size by 33%.
Another way to look at it is to create a table of 16 bit (0-65535) values. And for every 16 bit grouping, substitute a different character. But you would need 65536 unique characters to do this to restore the data.  So you aren't gaining anything.
Perhaps some compression algorithm like a huffman code might work.  But that and other compression algorithms tend to  work best on textual data and worse on binary data (compiled programs, audio, etc);

You input contains log(2, 10^38)~126.2 bits of information.
You have 20 characters,  so log(2, 10^38)/20~6.3 bits per character.
Which mean you need alphabet consisting of 2^(log(2, 10^38)/20)~79.4 characters.
TLDR: You need base80 encoding.

True.  But how would this work?  Even knowing the base, it doesn't seem possible to repack a binary number into a smaller, ASCII String.  Especially if it is printable.

I never said it possible. It depends on what you consider printable ASCII character. If we go with: everything between 32 and 128 it give us 96 characters, so more then enough to achieve result. If you only use [a-zA-Z0-9] then we 18 character short.
